# Class decorators in ES7

Tags: reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-2016

I've been reading up on decorators in JavaScript, and think I'm getting the basic premise.

Decorators are functions, they receive as a or several parameters what they should decorate, and return the result.

But I came over a `@withStyles` decorated implementation in a React Boiler Plate project which I do not understand how works.

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

function withStyles(...styles) {
  return (BaseComponent) => class StyledComponent extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      insertCss: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.removeCss = this.context.insertCss.apply(undefined, styles);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.removeCss();
    }

    render() {
      return <BaseComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}

export default withStyles;
```

A use case would be

```js
import s from './MyComponentStyle.scss';

@withStyles(s)
class MyComponent extends Component {

}
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Class decorators can be used as factory functions. For Example:

```js
function myDecorator(value) {
   return function(target) {
      target.myProperty = value;
   }
}

@myDecorator('myValue')
class MyClass { }
```

In your example the factory function returns constructor function which wraps original class. This function is used to create object instead of the original class. In your case it handles events (`componentWillMount`, `componentWillUnmount`) in order to insert/remove css and renders the original component with it's props.

This is very simple example demonstrating how is the original constructor function overrided by decorator:

```js
function myDecorator(name) {
   return (target) => class Wrapper {
       sayHello() {
           const targetObject = new target();
           console.log(`wrapper ${name} says hello`);
           targetObject.sayHello();
       }
       wrapperMethod() {
           console.log('calling wrapper function');
       }
   };
}

@myDecorator('Jack')
class MyClass {
    sayHello() {
        console.log('original says hello');
    }
    myMethod() {
       console.log('calling original function');
    }
}

var obj = new MyClass();

obj.sayHello();
//wrapper Jack says hello
//original says hello

obj.wrapperMethod();
//calling wrapper function

obj.myMethod();
//TypeError: obj.myMethod is not a function
```