# Static method is undefined in ES6 classes with a decorator in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

I have an ES6 class with a decorator. It has a static method foo. However when I try to access the static method, its undefined.

```
@withStyles(styles)
class MyComponent extends Component {
    static foo(){
        return "FOO";
    }
    render(){
        var x = MyComponent.foo; // x=undefined
    }
}
```

When I remove the decorator I can access the static method. Its no longer undefined.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    static foo(){
        return "FOO";
    }
    render(){
        var x = MyComponent.foo; // x=foo()
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Decorators are not part of ES6 / ES2015. This is probably a bug in the transpiler you're using (babel?).

Comment: What does the decorator do? Either your transpiler or the decorator implementation seems to be buggy.

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766822/class-decorators-in-es7?rq=1) explains how the withStyles decorator works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `babel` with `es6`, it could be transpiled like that (to `es5`):

```
var MyComponent = (function () {
  function MyComponent() {
    _classCallCheck(this, _MyComponent);
  }

  _createClass(MyComponent, null, [{
    key: 'foo',
    value: function foo() {
      return "FOO";
    }
  }]);

  var _MyComponent = MyComponent;
  Foo = withStyles(MyComponent) || MyComponent;
  return MyComponent;
})();
```

So its problem is that `withStyles(MyComponent)` will return another function which obviously doesn't have static methods you specified for original class.

Comment: Got it. Do you have around for this?

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766822/class-decorators-in-es7?rq=1) explains how the withStyles decorator works.

Comment: @GunnerFan I don't understand exactly how this answer solved your problem. I've stumbled on the exact same issue with a custom made decorator. Did you manage to solve it without rewriting your class?